# Uiscrollview scrolls horizontally and vertically

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

I have UI textview inside UIscrollView, so UIscrollview scrolls horizontally and vertically at the same time. is there any way to disable scrolling in horizontal way and enable scrolling to the vertical way ?

thank you

Comment: Are you aware that `UITextView` extends `UIScrollView`?

Answer (score 1):

If your scrollView scrolls horizontally, that's means that your textView or another subview is wider than the scrollView's frame.